Ideal refractive index of a thin film coating
My professor wrote that the refractive index of a thin film when we do a coating of it (say on glass to make them non reflective or anything) should be
$n_f = \sqrt{n_1 \cdot n_3}
$
Why should it be the geometric mean of the substrate and the outer medium?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-reflective_coating#Single-layer_interference (Doesn't show the math but explains how this formula is an approximation that is only exactly correct for a certain specific thickness of the coating)

do you know what a quarter-wave transmission line transformer is?

A simple anti reflection coating is a single layer of a dielectric on top of glass. There are two interfaces - Air to dielectric and dielectric to glass. Light reflects off both interfaces. The coating works by making the two reflections cancel each other as shown. See Anti-Reflection (AR) Coatings

The picture shows light striking at an angle. Most coatings are designed for normal incidence. A single layer AR coating is designed for a single wavelength. This is typically $550$ nm in the center of the visible spectrum. It works reasonably well at red and blue wavelengths, but not perfectly. This is why glasses look a little purple. Coating on optical components intended for lasers are designed for the laser wavelength.
The Fresnel equations give the coefficient of reflectivity at an interface. At normal incidence, it is
$$R = \left| \frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2} \right|^2$$
For good cancellation, you want $R_1=R_2$, or
$$\left| \frac{n_1-n_f}{n_1+n_f} \right|^2= \left| \frac{n_f-n_2}{n_f+n_2} \right|^2$$
Solving for $n_f$ gives your professor's result.
